# XMLTABLE solution without getting right parenthesis missing error

Tags: oracle, xml, oracle-12c

I am trying to select from an XML type and produce multiple rows. Have searched for my specific scenario/issue with not much success. Environment: Oracle 12c. I have commented out the offending code.

```
WITH XML_DATA AS  
    (SELECT XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <response>
        <phone>
            <number>859111</number>
            <contactModes>
                <mode>AUTO_DIAL</mode>
                <mode>AUTO_TEXT</mode>
                <mode>MANUAL_DIAL</mode>
            </contactModes>
            <contactableTimeRange>
                <day1>
                    <startTime>08:00:00</startTime>
                  <endTime>20:00:00</endTime>
                </day1>
                <day2>
                    <startTime>08:00:00</startTime>
                    <endTime>20:00:00</endTime>
                </day2>
            </contactableTimeRange>
        </phone>
    </response>') doc
    FROM DUAL)
SELECT X.phone
    ,x3.d1starttime
    ,x3.d1endtime
    /*,x4.* */
    FROM XML_DATA XD,  
    XMLTABLE('/response/phone' PASSING XD.DOC  
         COLUMNS phone  VARCHAR2(36) PATH 'number',  
                CONTACT_MODES XMLTYPE PATH 'contactModes',  
                CONTACT_TIMES XMLTYPE PATH 'contactableTimeRange')  X  
      /*  , XMLTABLE('/contactModes' 
       passing x.contact_modes
       COLUMNS  modes VARCHAR2(10) 'node' ) AS  x2*/
       ,XMLTABLE('/contactableTimeRange/day1' PASSING X.CONTACT_TIMES  
                COLUMNS D1STARTTIME VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'startTime',  
                        D1ENDTIME VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'endTime') AS X3  
       ,XMLTABLE('/contactableTimeRange/day2' PASSING X.CONTACT_TIMES  
                COLUMNS D2STARTTIME VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'startTime',  
                D2ENDTIME VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'endTime') X4;
```

I would like the query the return the following records. The mode values are not static, could be more or less. And same thing for the days. Could be day1 ..dayn

```
Phone      MODE      DAY    STARTTIME     ENDTIME  
859111    AUTO_DIAL   1    08:00:00  20:00:00  
859111    AUTO_DIAL   2    08:00:00  20:00:00  
859111    AUTO_TEXT   1    08:00:00  20:00:00  
859111    AUTO_TEXT   2    08:00:00  20:00:00  
859111    MANUAL_DIAL 1    08:00:00  20:00:00  
859111    MANUAL_DIAL 2    08:00:00  20:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have wanted this:

```
WITH XML_DATA AS
(SELECT XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <phone>
        <number>859111</number>
        <contactModes>
            <mode>AUTO_DIAL</mode>
            <mode>AUTO_TEXT</mode>
            <mode>MANUAL_DIAL</mode>
        </contactModes>
        <contactableTimeRange>
            <day1>
                <startTime>08:00:00</startTime>
              <endTime>20:00:00</endTime>
            </day1>
            <day2>
                <startTime>08:00:00</startTime>
                <endTime>20:00:00</endTime>
            </day2>
        </contactableTimeRange>
    </phone>
</response>') doc
FROM DUAL)
SELECT X.phone
,x2."MODE"
,To_Number (SubStr (x3.Day, 4)) Day
,x3.starttime
,x3.endtime
/*,x4.* */
FROM XML_DATA XD,
XMLTABLE('/response/phone' PASSING XD.DOC
     COLUMNS phone  VARCHAR2(36) PATH 'number',
            CONTACT_MODES XMLTYPE PATH 'contactModes',
            CONTACT_TIMES XMLTYPE PATH 'contactableTimeRange')  X
   , XMLTABLE('/contactModes/mode'
   passing x.contact_modes
   COLUMNS "MODE" VARCHAR2(10) Path '.' ) AS  x2
   ,XMLTABLE('/contactableTimeRange/*' PASSING X.CONTACT_TIMES
            COLUMNS Day VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'name()',
                    STARTTIME VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'startTime',
                    ENDTIME VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'endTime') AS X3
```

Which produces:

```
    PHONE                                MODE              DAY STARTTIME  ENDTIME
    ------------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- --------
    859111                               AUTO_DIAL           1 08:00:00   20:00:00
    859111                               AUTO_DIAL           2 08:00:00   20:00:00
    859111                               AUTO_TEXT           1 08:00:00   20:00:00
    859111                               AUTO_TEXT           2 08:00:00   20:00:00
    859111                               MANUAL_DIA          1 08:00:00   20:00:00
    859111                               MANUAL_DIA          2 08:00:00   20:00:00
```